# OpenCV in the Playground

Tags: c++, opencv, frameworks, objective-c++, swift-playground

It is possible to wrap C++ code with Objective-C++ frameworks for use in Swift code, including Playground environment. Some of my frameworks include OpenCV libraries and this works well in Swift when properly wrapped. Unfortunately, I cannot use these in playgrounds because of the following error:

```
Playground execution failed: error: Couldn't lookup symbols: _OBJC_CLASS_$_MyClass
```

... where `MyClass` is a subclass of `NSObject` from my framework. In fact, no framework symbols are available to the playground after I link to one of the OpenCV libraries (e.g. after adding `-lopencv_core` to "Other Linker Flags" in Build Settings), whether or not these symbols have anything to do with OpenCV (or C++ for that matter).

I very much enjoy developing small bits of functionality in playgrounds in the context of the imported frameworks where the successful solutions will eventually end up. Equally, OpenCV is an important library for me, so having to play with it in the playgrounds would be liberating (not to mention fun).

I'm still using Swift 1.2 (OS 10.10.4) as I'm about to submit an update to App Store, but I would be interested if Swift 2 makes any difference in this regard. As for OpenCV, this is version 3.0.0, built with CMake and default configuration.

Edit: Just found this problem described (better and more generally than I did) in the Apple's forums: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/6246